# PHP submit form data which has multiple images and text data.. where all the field names and ids are dynamic

Tags: php, html, mysql

I m new in PHP, was creating a form that can have a multiple numbers of input fields with images and text data.
While submitting the from details I wanna read all the data and save it into our database.
But the challenge it how can I read all the $post data if the field ids and names are unknown(run time generated).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>form details</title>
  </head>
<body>
   <form role="form" method="post" id="form" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <li class="cards_item">
<div class="card">
<div class="card_content">
<canvas id="input_id_6d0e13aed5f64a57993085c69d866ff2"></canvas>
<input type="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*" id="finput_6d0e13aed5f64a57993085c69d866ff2" />
<textarea id="TextInput_6d0e13aed5f64a57993085c69d866ff2" name="Text area name" class="form-element-field" placeholder="none" type="text" ></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</li>

<li class="cards_item">
<div class="card">
<div class="card_content">
<canvas id="input_id_bfb25544ca4d409db4d969f7451ad363"></canvas>
<input type="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*" id="finput_bfb25544ca4d409db4d969f7451ad363" />
<textarea id="TextInput_bfb25544ca4d409db4d969f7451ad363" name="Text area name" class="form-element-field" placeholder="none" type="text" ></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</li>
 

and so on......can be any number of cards

</form>
```

Now on submit I wanna take all the data one by one and save that into database.

Comment: As all fields are stored in `$_POST`, why not just iterate over them? If **all** field names are dynamic, is there any system behind them for matching them on your application fields?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Note that

> $_POST is an associative array indexed by form element NAMES, not IDs.

Your code has multiple inputs with the same name.

So, if your html like this:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="form" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*" id="finput_1" name="finput_1" />
        <textarea name="TextInput_1" type="text"></textarea>
        <textarea name="TextInput_2" type="text"></textarea>
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

You can access POSTED data by using for/foreach loop and `$_POST` global variable.
Also you can access Files by `$_FILES` global variable.
Like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $inputName = $key;
        $inputValue = $value;
    }

    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
        $inputName = $key;
        $inputValue = $value;

        $fileName = $value['name'] ?? "";
        $fileType = $value['type'] ?? "";
        $fileTmpName = $value['tmp_name'] ?? "";
        $fileError = $value['error'] ?? "";
        $fileSize = $value['size'] ?? "";
    }
}
```

Please note that you will need to run some validation to your data.

Comment: First of all, Thank you so much at least now I m getting all the details of whatever i m Submitting..

But now I m getting another issue.. after submitting the form I can see the file details with logs.. but when I m trying to move the file from temp folder to my actual directory.. 
  There is no error but the file doesn't move.. I m not sure what's wrong with this function but it's not moving the temp file to the destination dir...
I m using the below funciton to move my files 

$destinationFolder = 'uploads/'.$fileNewName ; 
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $destinationFolder);

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer works for you, You should mark it as answer.
You can make another question with more details and your code for your other problem, so we can help you better.